# Uber: Does Access Token is valid for per user or all users?

Tags: api, integration

I am tying to integrate with uber API. I have successfully generated the access token and refresh token. Now i need to save this both in database. Before that i have query, do i need to store this (access token and refresh token), for per user or i can use them for all users.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all scenarios, and yes, therefore I can conclude that, access token is validate to per user, if you generated the new access token then also it automatically relates to your old access token. And you can use both or more access token before it expired.